# NodeJS template engine for jQueryMobile

Tags: node.js, jquery-mobile

what template engine is recommended for NodeJS when using jQueryMobile Multi-Page template?

I need logic in every view such as include_once('html-header') because I never know is current page is first on rendering list (aka does it match session-privilege criteria).

I've tried Jade but it seems to be completely impropriety solution for such problems. But maybe my design is wrong?

Probably something simmilar to PHP with <? and <?= will be best to fit my project needs.

**Edit:**
I'm using nodejs as a HTTP server.

Comment: Are you serving the html from the jqueryMobile app or from the Node.JS server?

Answer (score 0):

You can use emberjs and detect the states and you can append and delete views as you need them to the outlet, Ember uses handlebars template engine to render html

[Emberjs](http://emberjs.com/)

[Also check outlets in this page](http://emberjs.com/guides/router_primer/)